# Bring the suggested edits count back to the review button on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, review, top-bar

The new interaction of review icon is awesome.

When drop down, it show the count on each category.

But, previously in the icon, it showed the suggested edit count.

Now it doesn't.

> [image]

It will be good if the suggested edit count is shown on the button.

Comment: That number was never correct, search for it and you'll find dozen of reports. Let's not bring that confusing number back.

Comment: @Glorfindel [Also the dropdown list is not in any order](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346610/2451726)

Comment: @rene, the numbers change time to time. If it show 97 on the icon, when we load the page, it show a differwnt count. It changes in each seconds I think. Because SO has a huge number of edit suggestors and reviewers

Comment: @rene that is less relevant. Point here, I guess, is to quickly see if something needs attention, so that edits won't wait for long time until approved.

Comment: Also, since this exists only on Stack Overflow voting to close, it better fit in MSO. (if and when it will be on more sites it can always be reopened)

Answer (score 5):

> It will be good if the suggested edit count is shown on the button

Why? Good for what? The button is highlighted when there are available reviews, so those who want to review will just click it and see the numbers. It's one click away. And those who are not interested in reviewing won't be bothered any more by something that is just noise for them.